# Integrate CPPUTest in Keil

Tags: unit-testing, keil, cpputest

I am a fresher in CPPUTest and I already have a project ready in Keil. Now, I need to test the project in Keil using CPPUTest. Can anyone help me on how to integrate and use CPPUTest on Keil in Windows for already existing project.

As I have mentioned I already have a project and I just need instructions on how to integrate CPPUTest in Keil on Windows.

Thanks and Regards,
K.Kanthi Deep.